# Generate all permutations, ommitting those not in least to greatest order

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of numbers, 1-33. I need a fast way to generate every permutation of three of these numbers that results in an ascending order.

Examples:
7 19 25
1 2 3
10 20 30

But not:
7 5 9
11 23 22

Is there a way to do this in Excel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
Sub Testing123()

Dim seedMax As Integer

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer

    seedMax = 33

    For a = 1 To seedMax
        For b = a + 1 To seedMax
            For c = b + 1 To seedMax
                Debug.Print a, b, c
            Next c
        Next b
    Next a

End Sub
```

Writing it to a worksheet:

```
Sub Testing123withSheetWrite()

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer

Dim seedMax As Integer: seedMax = 33

Dim x As Long: x = 1
Dim y As Long: y = 1

    For a = 1 To seedMax
        For b = a + 1 To seedMax
            For c = b + 1 To seedMax
                Debug.Print a, b, c
                Cells(x, y + 0) = a
                Cells(x, y + 1) = b
                Cells(x, y + 2) = c
                x = x + 1
            Next c
        Next b
    Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `For a = 1 To seedMax - 2` and `For b = a + 1 To seedMax - 1` ?

Comment: I've pasted this into a VBA Macro and assigned it to a key combination. Do I select a cell in the spreadsheet and run the script?

Comment: @Jeeped, the VBA runs fine "as is" without having to clarify boundaries.  If you run into anything different, please let me know :)

Comment: @CRBTC - you didn't specify where you wanted the output, so I provided you with a simple solution that satisfied the requirement of generating the list.  The output is sent to the IMMEDIATE WINDOW, which is available in the VBA Editor environment. You can either click the green PLAY arrow while your cursor is within the code block, or hit F5 and specify the macro name to run.  If you need something more, please don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: @flaZer Ah I see. That should be fine, only it doesn't seem to generate at all for me. I'm sure I've made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @CRBTC - It probably does - there just isn't enough 'storage' to hold everything so what doesn't fit roles out of the Immediate Window buffer.  I'll tweak the solution to write onto a worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

This will generate all 5456 combinations of the integers from 1 to 33

```
Sub ListUm()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, Z As Long
    Z = 1
    For i = 1 To 31
        For j = i + 1 To 32
            For k = j + 1 To 33
                Cells(Z, 1) = i & "," & j & "," & k
                Z = Z + 1
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Since you have a specified order you can use **combinations** rather than **permutations**.

Comment: I came up with 5456 combinations - did I mess up?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `A1`,`B1`,`C1` with `1`,`2`,`3`,
then enter

```
=IF((B1=32)*(C1=33),A1+1,A1)
```

in `A2`,

```
=IF(A2=A1,IF(C1<33,B1,B1+1),A2+1)
```

in `B2` and

```
=MAX(B2+1,MOD(C1,33)+1)
```

in `C2`

[image]

Then copy/drag cells `A2:C2` down until the last line, `31`,`32`, `33`:

[image]